# Find a sequence that is divergent but its average converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let ${t_n}=\frac{s_1+s_2+...+s_n}{n}\text{   where  }  n \ge 1$.  Find an example showing ${t_n}$ may converge even though ${s_n}$ diverges.

Can anyone think of an example?

Comment: Thank you swapnil for fixing the formatting.  I was just about to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple one.

$\{s_n\} =(-1)^n$ would do the trick.

Note: $t_n=\frac{s_1+s_2+...s_n}{n}=\frac{(-1)}{n}$ when $n$ is odd and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you!  I don't know why I was having such a hard time coming up with something.

Comment: Such a sequence ($\{s_n\}$) is not diverging: it is a bounded non-converging sequence.

Comment: Oh! Yes, I will delete that in a while. So there won't be any such example? @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: You'd like to read Jack's comment before accepting. Or maybe you too mistook divergent for non-convergent? @Brianna

Comment: But divergent := non-convergent, so there is no problem with this example.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Thank you for clearing the doubt!